# Kentico. Is it possible to place a dynamic value in a query?

Tags: kentico

Using the "Repeater with Custom Query" webpart.  Is it possible to have your select statement (query) looking for a dynamic value.  So something like; 
SELECT ##TOPN## ##COLUMNS## FROM Form_table.table WHERE Form_table.table.RecordKey = 'RecordKey480nypxock'. The value of "RecordKey" is dynamic from the page. I can not hard code a given value into the query being it will always change depending on the user record needing to be accessed.  Is it possible to pickup a value through jQuery or some other option off the page (UI)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I recommend that is, the web part should have a "Where Condition" property. That matches up with ##WHERE## so you'd say ELECT ##TOPN## ##COLUMNS## FROM Form_table.table WHERE ##WHERE##.
And then that WhereCondition field would say "Form_table.table.RecordKey = '{% MyMacroToGetAValue() %}'"
Given that you want to pick it up from the UI, I'd recommend using a QueryString macro {? QSValue ?}.

If you're asking 'can I use it to pick up a value from the *current* UI', then no. It's a server-side query, so you could certainly do some stuff with an UpdatePanel, maybe pick it up from a session variable/cookie or something on postback. Or you could fire a page request within an inner iframe, and pull the data out that way... But the repeater only runs during a server-side request.